YOLO v8 train works well but I can't see val loss metrics(box_loss cls_loss seg_loss dfl_loss)
enter image description here
enter image description here
I can train the model and model is predicting test videos. But I can't see val loss graphs at the end.`
!yolo task=segment mode=train model=yolov8l-seg.pt data={dataset.location}/data.yaml epochs=25 imgsz=544 batch=2 amp=False val=True plots=True

I searched but I didn't see anything about this problem.
I tried changing dataset, imgsize, batchsize, learning rate.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
